# When you report a profile on Mastodon for violating the server's rules, who gets the report?

Tags: mastodon

When you're viewing a profile on Mastodon you have the option to report that profile. Does a report on Mastodon for "violating server rules" go to,

- The server that is federated that hosts the profile?
- Your server, that hosts your profile?

Presumably there are two sets of rules,

- The rules the user has that they're bound to on their own server
- The rules of your own server for federation

All of this is very confusing when you want to report a profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *deep* [in their documentation](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/user/moderating/#report) but it reports it to your admin by default *then* there's an option to report it to their admin. The 'flow' seems to be, report the user, pick posts to report, then when confirming and adding additional information you can confirm it, and choose to report it to the admin.

For the purposes of 'full' documentation — the flow looks something like this. I am on a different server, which is better for the purposes of documentation, and this is from the web client. The flow may vary on a mobile client.

[image: options: I don't like it, It's spam, It violates server rules, It's something else]

("I don't like it" gives you a mute/block option)

[image: Are there any posts that back up this report?]
This gives a selection of posts to report on

[image: Is there anything else you think we should know? (Input box) The account is from another server. Send an anonymized copy of the report there as well? (Checkbox) Forward to hachyderm.io]

Here, you can choose to report it to the profile's admin too

Comment: Image quality of screenshots is poor. Reccomend reposting higher resolution versions. If reason for the quality is to  manage display dimensions, this can also be achieved via markdown tags without compromising image quality:`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyWn1m.png" width="233" />`  To  also link reduced image to original: `[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyWn1m.png" width="233" />][1] `  alternatively `[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyWn1m.png" width="233" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyWn1m.png)`